# Is it possible to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to programatically remove line numbering from a Word document?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I would like to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to programatically [remove *all* line numberings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-line-numbers-b67cd35e-422c-42eb-adc9-256ca9802e22#remove) from a Word document. (How) is it possible?

Should I use the [LineNumbering interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.linenumbering.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line numbering is an document- or section-level setting, and it's controlled over the `PageSetup` object. To simply turn it off throughout the document:

```
Word.Document doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
doc.PageSetup.LineNumbering.Active = false;
```

Comment: Here's a C# implementation: https://gist.github.com/Manzanit0/8ee560edb07103179d845704d8ea2ecb